# Auto-updating variable

Tags: python, variables

I have a list that contains one or many items:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'] #or could be one or many
```

I want to create variables depending on the number of items:
Code:

```
    for i in range(len(fruits)):
        "Fruit".format(i) = fruits[i]
```

I want to obtain as:

```
    Fruit1=apple, Fruit2=orange, Fruit3=pear
```

Any help how I can get this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop)

Comment: First and foremost, your assignment is backwards.

Comment: His/her assignment isn't backward. He/she wants to create multiple named variables from the items in the list. The syntax in the question won't work, and it's a bad idea to begin with, but that's why he/she asked the question.

Comment: The reason why I want it like that is because, I want to be able to print it depending on the number of elements.
         print ("Fruit".format(i))

Answer (score 1):

As a proper way for such tasks you can use a dictionary :

```
>>> fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
>>> d={"Fruit{}".format(i):j for i,j in enumerate(fruits,1)}
>>> d
{'Fruit1': 'apple', 'Fruit2': 'orange', 'Fruit3': 'pear'}
>>> d['Fruit1']
'apple'
```

*Note* that if you use a data structure like dictionary for your problem you will get a lot of advantages like, that you can access to all of your values with `dict.values()` and all of the keys with `dict.keys()` also it could be more easier for interaction with another data structures!

```
>>> d.keys()
['Fruit1', 'Fruit2', 'Fruit3']
>>> d.values()
['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
```

Comment: I don't think the OP intended to use a dictionary. I think he just wanted a list with the fruit number in the string.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi yeah, i know that but this is a flexible and more extensible way! for such tasks!

Comment: Might want to throw the start parameter of `1` to `enumerate` as the OP appears to want 1-based indexing...

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, your assignment is backwards. You're trying to set a list index in a string instead of a string in a list index. Otherwise, I suggest using the enumerate function. Don't be tripped up by my formatting, there are my ways to do so in Python.

```
for i, j in enumerate(fruits):
    fruits[i] = "Fruit%d=%s" % (i + 1, j)
```